# Trying to use browserless ... getting "message: 'elements' is not allowed"

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape an Amazon page with [browserless](https://www.browserless.io/):

```sh
curl -X POST \
  "https://chrome.browserless.io/content?token=<token>" \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d ' { 
   "url": "https://www.amazon.com/gp/your-account/order-details/?orderID=114-5444651-3149007",
   "elements": [{
      "selector": "a",
   }],
   "cookies": [
         <many cookies>
      ],
}'
```

but I keep getting:

```json
[{"message":"\"elements\" is not allowed","path":["elements"],"type":"object.unknown","context":{"child":"elements","label":"elements","value":[{"selector":"a","timeout":10000}],"key":"elements"}}]%
```

If I exclude the `elements` object, it works fine but returns the entire 6,000 lines of `<html>`.

(What I actually want is `document.getElementsByClassName('shipment')[0].innerText`)

When I try the examples (from the [docs](https://docs.browserless.io/docs/scrape.html)) they work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Its because elements only available for [/scrape](https://docs.browserless.io/docs/scrape.html) API

You are using [/content](https://docs.browserless.io/docs/scrape.html)